# Remote desktop not working (windows 10)

Tags: windows-10, remote-desktop, cisco-vpn-client

I have a desktop computer in my office that runs a remote desktop server (I checked it, and port 3389 is listening). However, I can't connect to it from my home PC (with cisco any connect vpn). The IT support was able to use my credentials to connect to it, so I guess the problem is on my side.

So far, I have tried:

1. setting `Computer\HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\RDGClientTransport` in regedit to 1
2. making sure that `Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Terminal Server\fDenyTSConnections` in regedit is 0
3. setting `Computer\HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Terminal Server Client\RDGClientTransport` to 1
4. turning off the firewall
5. Make sure that no other app is using the 3389 port

However, it still gives me a very generic error.

```
Remote Desktop can’t connect to the remote computer for one of these reasons:

1) Remote access to the server is not enabled
2) The remote computer is turned off
3) The remote computer is not available on the network
```

Comment: "The IT support was able to use my credentials to connect to it," but did they do that *within* the office LAN, or outside it, as you'd be at home? "3. The remote computer is not available on the network," could be because of that. Suggest you bring in the desktop (or a more-convenient laptop) and try RD in the office on the LAN, *then after that is working, with IT help*, try it at home.

Comment: It only works if I'm not on the office LAN, not sure what the IT support used though